# Can not post Google Apps Marketplace Listing Review Request for API Project

Tags: google-oauth, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

My requirement is to enable `OAuth 2.0` for an existing `OAuth 1.0` application in `Google Apps Marketplace`.
I have created new Google project in the [console](https://cloud.google.com/console/) and created a listing for it. And now I need to submit `Google Apps Marketplace Listing Review Request`. As it is an API project that uses only `Google Apps Marketplace SDK` so I can not make a review request for my app listing. As I don't have any APIs listed in the required section the request submission failed.

The app and listing is tested installing to a test domain owned by the owner(creator) of the app and project.

For app publishing used [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing) document, for project creation used [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing) document.

My question is how can a project which use only Google Apps Marketplace SDK be published? Is there an alternative way to do that like creating only to the Crome Web Store instead of publishing to Google Apps Marketplace?

### Edit :

Following is the scope setting code and user details retrieving code I use in the programming/implementation end of the application.

```
// Create new instance of Google_Client
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId(GOOGLE_APP_CLIENT_ID);
// Set client secret
$client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_APP_CLIENT_SECRET);
// Set redirect URI, this matches the Redirect URIs set in OAuth 2.0 client settings
$client->setRedirectUri(GOOGLE_APP_CLIENT_REDIRECT_URI);
// Set scopes
$client->addScope("openid profile email");

// Create a OAuth 2 service instance
$oauth2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);

// Verify code and access_token
......
// Get user information and signup the user
$guser_info = $oauth2->userinfo->get();

// Get required user information infiormation
$firstName = $guser_info['givenName'];
$lastName = $guser_info['familyName'];
$userEmail= strtolower( filter_var($guser_info['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL) );
```

Enabled APIs in the Developer Console are

1. Google Apps Marketplace SDK
2. Google+ API

Scopes set in the Google Apps Marketplace SDK are (first two are set by default)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google Apps Marketplace listing policies, not programming.

Comment: Do you actually need to list it to the public store? If you publish to a trusted tester group or limit it to your domain in the Visibility Options found in the Chrome Developer Dashboard.

Comment: @jonathanberi, Yes. I need to publish it to public store. New app is created to enable OAuth 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Google is shifting away entirely from the "Apps Marketplace" and focusing on the Chrome Web Store.  You *can* list an API project on the Chrome Web Store, but you kind of also have to include a defined extension or web app for it to install correctly.