# Cannot submit app to google app marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

I am integrating google app marketplace SDK to my web app and publishing it to chrome web store as specified [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing)

I have published the app to restricted users (domain users only) to test the workflow.

The app is published to the domain users but when I access it and click to install, it adds as a chrome extension but I cannot access it as a Google Marketplace app.

For marketplace integration, I have created a project under Google APIs Console and enabled Google Apps Marketplace SDK. If I click the "Test Install Flow" button

[image]

the app is successfully installed as a marketplace app which I can access from universal app navigator of my domain email.

**Question**

Is this the best way I can test whether the app installs as a marketplace application for restricted users? Can I not see it added by directly installing it from the published url?

I have gone through a few links which mention that it is now not easy to submit app to marketplace unless you use atleast one of the Google Services APIs and get through the  Google Apps Marketplace Listing Review Request.

[Can not post Google Apps Marketplace Listing Review Request for API Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988474/can-not-post-google-apps-marketplace-listing-review-request-for-api-project)
[How to create listing on google apps marketplace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22632154/how-to-create-listing-on-google-apps-marketplace)

If I do not intend to use any of the Google Services APIs, and just use Google App MarketPlace SDK, will I not be able to get the app listed in marketplace?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have added both "DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE" and "GOOGLE_DRIVE" in your mainfest.json file. Try adding "app" section to the manifest. See https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide

Comment: Yes I have added both "DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE" and "GOOGLE_DRIVE". If I add app section in manifest file, it doesn't get uploaded giving an error to remove app section

Comment: If you don't intent for your app to be a Drive App, then remove the GOOGLE_DRIVE container from your manifest (as well as the app section) and try uploading that.

Comment: I have an web application which develop different mobile apps and other services. I want my app to be present on g Suite marketplace. Is it possibilble ? Till now I have website and I am using useing my web app from there. It contains "Login with google" functionality and if user added sheet or calender page then Google sheet and Google calender also get used. Anyone can guide me regarding this ? I have already created project on developer console and test intallation flow.